# brew install any tools caused failure

Tags: homebrew

I’ve macOS High Sierra 10.13.3, and I found recently using Homebrew to install some tools cause problems. Any installation will cause that showing below:

```
$ brew install ethereum
Error: No available formula with the name "ethereum" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
This formula was found in a tap:
caskroom/cask/ethereum-wallet
To install it, run:
  brew install caskroom/cask/ethereum-wallet
```

I successfully used brew to install before, but after I upgrade the OS, the problem firstly occurs. If I run "brew doctor", it shows:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /opt/local/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /opt/local/bin/pcre-config
  /opt/local/bin/ncurses6-config

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
```

Comment: Hello please check here if you got your ans. by my below ans.

Comment: I tried to uninstall fink by "sudo rm -rf /sw" and then brew install ethereum,the problem still ocurrs.

Comment: There’s no formula (package) for `ethereum`. Your installation is fine, the issue is just that you try to install something that doesn’t exist.